# How can I run XCTest in my project there was a runtime error occur

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I create a Xcode Framework project, and then I use CocoaPods to import another module. Then I want to write a Unit Test.

But when Unit Test run, there has been an run time error

```
2019-02-02 10:20:39.157536+0800 xctest[90385:6327514] The bundle “XXX” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.
2019-02-02 10:20:39.157855+0800 xctest[90385:6327514] (dlopen_preflight(/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-dfsjsywxidmqgmaudrhgrhgniihc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XXX.xctest/XXXTests): Library not loaded: @rpath/XXX1.framework/XXX1
  Referenced from: /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-dfsjsywxidmqgmaudrhgrhgniihc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XXX.framework/XXX
  Reason: image not found)
Program ended with exit code: 82
```

How can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Podfile`, make sure that your module is also available for your Unit Test target.

Here is an example, some pods inherited from the main target, other only available for testing purpose.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do

    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'
    pod 'ORStackView', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3'

    target 'MyAppTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        pod 'Quick'
    end
end
```

Comment: I do as blow steps 1. add Tests target 2. run pod install 3. clean my project 4. Start test 

But the error still exists

Comment: Another idea, make sure your `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` has the right settings and includes `$(inherited)` - https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4944#issuecomment-412902408.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh, this can not help, the error still exists, so should I make a issue on github?